# SSH using Google auth TOTP and pubkey still Requiring password

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Google Auth setup by following [this guide on linode.com](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/use-one-time-passwords-for-two-factor-authentication-with-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-debian-8/#combine-two-factor-and-public-key-authentication) and a pubkey (generated with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`) to ssh into a new Ubuntu server I have setup.

```
└─$ ssh -i .ssh/ubuntuServer USER@192.168.0.102 
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/ubuntuServer': 
(USER@192.168.0.102) Password: 
(USER@192.168.0.102) Verification code:
```

And I would ideally like to not put in the users password when logging in, as I already use a TOTP and a password for the keypair.

This is a copy of my sshd_config file:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
ClientAliveInterval 300
Protocol 2
ClientAliveCountMax 2
AllowUsers esmith

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

And this is a copy of my pam.d/sshd file:

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
#@include common-password

auth    required      pam_google_authenticator.so
```

In the end, this isn't a terrible issue, but it is a botherance and I'd like to know how to change it or just come to terms that I can't. If you have any thoughts, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you didn't comment out the lines in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` as advised in the guide you linked

Comment: @Nmath Are you sure? I looked again and that line doesn't appear in my file as I've removed it. I could just be blind but I don't see it. EDIT: I am in fact blind and dumb

Comment: The guide tells you to comment the line `# @include common-auth`, but in the config you posted, it is uncommented.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks, just after I replied I realized what I missed

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, I can post an answer

Comment: @Nmath It did! I was looking in the wrong area and you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you linked advises you to comment out a few lines in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Currently, the line that reads:

```
@include common-auth
```

should be changed to:

```
# @include common-auth
```